# Получить кропп, меньше операций

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
list($width, $height, $x, $y) = explode(':', explode('=', exec("ffmpeg -i {$vd} -ss 15 -t 30 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1"))[1]);
```

В целом та работает, получаю координаты кропа, единственное смущает - множество делений, explode.
Собственно вопрос в том, возможно ли иначе получить кроп, так же в каждую переменную запонить.

Операций бы поменьше хотя бы...

Comment: регулярные выражения в помощь. текст приведите, который `exec` возвращает

Comment: [Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x466ba40] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:375296 t:29.320000 crop=1280:720:0:0

Comment: можно  так `preg_match("/crop=([\d:]+)/", $txt, $m); [$w, $h, $x, $y] = explode(':', $m[1]);`